# IIS application pool turned off with event id 5009

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a website. It's an MVC5 web application, using the .NET Framework 4.6.2.

We have a compilation server running on Windows Server 2016, it has installed vsbuild tools 2017.

The compiled site works perfectly in my environment, in the testing environment and also in a clean installed windows vm, but in the production environment the first request to the site returns a 503 error code and the application pool turns off automatically. I've checked the event viewer and there is an event there with ID 5009: a process serving application pool x suffered a fatal communication error with the windows process activation service.

The problem doesn't reproduce with the compiled site in any other environment

Also if I compile the site in release using my own Visual Studio 2017 the problem doesn't reproduce in production environment neither.

Any suggestions?

Adding some information: I've captured a crashdump with DebugDiag2, this is what I think it's the relevant part of the log:

```
EXCEPTION DETAILS  

DetailID = 1
Count:    10
Exception #:  0XE06D7363
Stack: [NO STACK HERE]        

DetailID = 2
Count:    1
Type:     System.String
Message:  NOT_FOUND
Type:     NOT_FOUND
Message:  NOT_FOUND
Stack: [LONG STACK HERE]

DetailID = 3
Count:    1
Exception #:  0XC0000409
Stack: [NO STACK HERE]       

EXCEPTION SUMMARY

10 | 0XE06D7363  

1  | System.String

1  | 0XC0000409
```

I also requested the dump analysis from the tool, here is the summary:

In dumpfilename.dmp the assembly instruction at PerfMon!_invoke_watson+e in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Monitoring Agent\Agent\APMDOTNETAgent\V8.0.10918.0\PerfMon.dll from Microsoft Corp. has caused an unknown exception (0xc0000409) on thread 10

And also, in the first section of the dump analysis I found something really odd: It says: Operating system = Windows Server 2012 (which is right), Processor Type: X86 (which looks weird for me because as far as I know there is no Win2012 for x86)

I don't even know where to start =(

Comment: Looks like appliaction pool problems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735110(v=ws.10)

Comment: Also there are some MS patches that raise that error https://forums.iis.net/t/1239204.aspx?Warning+Event+ID+5009+5011+After+Jul+2018+windows+update

Comment: Get a crash dump and analyze it https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/

Comment: Hello everybody, thank you for the quick reply. I've saved a crush dump using debugdiag2 but I can't find the culprit yet. I'll be editing this question to add some info from the dump as soon as possible to continue the discussion. Thank you guys again!